# XmlPullParser unresolved: &ldquo

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse a document that is formatted similar to Xml (but not XML format) it works for everything except when I reach an HTML code like &ldquo. Then I get an error and everything crashes. How can I work around this?

Edit Here's the error and the line it happens on:

> 03-25 17:56:26.540: W/System.err(21265): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 68, column 354: undefined entity

> <F_S_INGREDIENTS>Pale ale malt (well-modified and suitable for single-temperature infusion mashing); American hops; American yeast that can give a clean or slightly fruity profile. Generally all-malt, but mashed at lower temperatures for high attenuation. Water character varies from soft to moderately sulfate. Versions with a noticeable Rye character (“RyePA”) should be entered in the Specialty category.</F_S_INGREDIENTS>

I've narrowed it down to “RyePA”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&ldquo` is a valid HTML entity, but not a valid XML entity. You aren't going to be able to parse it with a stock XML parser.

The [defineEntityReplacement()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#defineEntityReplacementText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method looks promising. If you can't get that to work for you, you can simply read the string into memory (if it's not too bug) and before you hand it off to the parser, replace the text yourself,

```
String s = xml.replaceAll("&ldpos;", "\"").replaceAll("&rdpos;", "\"");
```

Comment: sorry forgot to post it here it is:03-25 17:37:37.340: W/System.err(20355): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 68, column 354: undefined entity

Comment: that's not enough information. it doesn't say what entity is undefined, and you aren't posting what is at line 68 in your source .xml file.

Comment: Sorry again, a little tired, updated with the line in the file and the error

Comment: okay, see my edit. &ldquo; is not valid XML, although it is valid HTML. so you can modify your source files, or you look can look into how to make the parser handle that entity.